# Sorting a angular expansion panel

Tags: css, angular

i have a expansion panel with a lot of content. Currently its a total chaos and looks like this:

https://ibb.co/Y3z9gdf

So that looks no not very nice, is there any way to sort it or something else? With some more space like a list or similiar?

My Code:

```html
<div id="persontyp">
            <mat-expansion-panel > 

                <mat-expansion-panel-header  > Personentypen </mat-expansion-panel-header>
                    <mat-checkbox *ngFor="let type of allpersonTypes" [value]="type.bezeichnung">
                        {{type.bezeichnung}}
                    </mat-checkbox>
            </mat-expansion-panel>
        </div>
```

My CSS:

```html
mat-expansion-panel{
    padding: 5x;
    width: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mat-checkbox {
    display: block;
}
```

This is should work for you. In another case you can add !important to display: block;

P.S. If you want to separate it into 2 columns then use that:

```
<div id="persontyp">
  <mat-expansion-panel > 

      <mat-expansion-panel-header  > Personentypen </mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <div class="list-container">
        <mat-checkbox *ngFor="let type of allpersonTypes" [value]="type.bezeichnung">
            {{type.bezeichnung}}
        </mat-checkbox>
      </div>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.list-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
}
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. Yes that works, but now its all listed in 1 column. Is there a way to "break" it into 2 columns?

Comment: @ChopperChupss I edited my answer, check it, please.

Comment: exactly what i needed, thank you very much!

Comment: @ChopperChupss mark my answer as right :) and have a good day